# C# Drawing a radar scaling and centering problems

Tags: c#, math, coordinates

I would like to draw a radar on a pictureBox. Drawing points is no problem but I am struggling with basic maths. Maybe I am too tired.

I have a pictureBox that is 200x200. I have loaded a small, centered image inside the picturebox (4x4) which symbolizes the current player.

I have build a function called

> PaintRadar(int meX, int meY, int enemyX, int enemyY)

The parameters could have the following values: meX = 27000, meY = 30000, enemyX = 26000, enemyY = 28000

The desired result is to have the enemies around me and I am always centered in the pictureBox. What do I have to calculate to center meX and meY in the pictureBox?

Thanks

Comment: If you start with the assumption that `meX,meY` is 0,0, couldn't you then find the difference to `enemyX,enemyY`, and then scale accordingly to fit inside the picture box?

Comment: ...or you can translate/scale the **graphics** using [Graphics.TranslateTransform()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Graphics.ScaleTransform()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx(v=vs.110).aspx), then draw everything at it's original coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the player is in the middle of the enemies and draw the enemies around the center based on the difference between their positions and the player's position.

Think about it as though the player is the origin. By subtracting the player's position from the enemy's position you are putting the enemy position into a coordinate system with the player at the center. This is essentially what you're radar is.

Example:

```
// Get differences. d is short for difference (or delta :)).
int dy = enemyY - meY;
int dx = enemyX - meX;

// Then scale the dy and dx values so they fix in the picture box.
dy *= scaleY;
dx *= scaleX;
```

Then you would draw the enemies at (dx,dy) on the picture box.

Scale should be a formula like this:

```
scaleY = (1 / maxDetectionDistance) * (heightOfRadarBox / 2);
scaleX = (1 / maxDetectionDistance) * (widthOfRadarBox / 2);
```

Anything greater than your radar's limit should not be drawn.

```
// Don't draw if enemy is too far away for radar to pick up.
if (Math.Abs(dy) > maxDetectionDistance || Math.Abs(dx) > maxDetectionDistance)
{
    return;
}
```